# NginX reverse proxy based on path parameters

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding

I am quite new to NginX and I am trying to configure on the basis of path variable / parameter.

For ex: if requests come to **www.example.com**, direct them to `localhost:8080`, but if requests come with anything (**www.example.com/123** or **www.example.com/v1/**), it should be forwarded to another application running on `localhost:3001`.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If nginx is configured as a reverse/cache proxy server, then I think what you are looking for is:

```
location /123 {

        proxy_pass       http://localhost:3001;

}
```

Comment: but that `/123` part is dynamic. It can be anything. If request is coming for just **/**, I want one application to respond. If it comes for anything else **/{anything}**, it should go to a different application on a different port. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, the location can be a regex, but I don't have the exact code, maybe this would help: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: @Auro, you can use an exact match (`location = /`) for `http://localhost:8080` and a prefix match (`location /`) for the other one.